# How to change folder access if it says "You have unknown access"?

Tags: macos, permission, server.app

I installed OSX Server and activated FTP for Downloads folder. Now folder looks like file in Finder and Downloads info looks badly. Also when i trying to delete Downloads, OSX required password and then said *The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -8003).*

Screenshots: [image] [image: enter image descriptionhere][image]

Of course, first of all I disabled FTP and rebooted computer. It didn't helped.
I google the problem and found a solution, it says i would need perform couple command in terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/evlogii/Downloads
sudo chown -R evlogii:staff /Users/evlogii/Downloads
```

As you understand "evlogii" is my username. It performed without any errors but didn't helped. Please help me recover normal condition of my Downloads folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before, on the Downloads folder, and on other folders. Removing the directory and it's contents, and recreating the directory worked for me.

The commands below are to be entered in the Terminal

Copy content before deleting:

`mkdir ~/Temp
sudo cp -R  ~/Downloads ~/Temp/
sudo chmod -R 755  ~/Temp`

To remove your damaged Downloads folder:

`rm -rf ~/Downloads`, or if that doesn't work, `sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads`

To recreate a new empty one after removal:

`mkdir ~/Downloads; chown $USER ~/Downloads`

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. In the last step could you just rename the ~/Temp folder to ~/Downloads?

Comment: @Coconutdog Yes, you could